# AS3 creating HTML links in an article

Tags: html, regex, actionscript-3, hyperlink

I have a Wiki program that works locally and organizes articles and adds HTML links that link to functions (to load subsequent articles).

Some code to wrap your head around:

```
for each (var keyword:String in thisArticleArray) {
  var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp(keyword,'/gi');
  contents = contents.replace(pattern,"<a href=\"event:" + "$&" + "\"><b>" + keyword + "</b></a>");
}
```

Anyways, the idea is that these links link to new articles. That isn't so bad. But now, I have articles with names that contain other article names. Example would be "Apple" and "Apple Pie". How would I differentiate between these? Right now it just screws up when it hits that area...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would simply reverse-sort `thisArticleArray` by string length.  This way the code will always attempt to match the longer matches before the shorter ones.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to actually write regular expression? If you set /Apple/gi as RegEx

```
new RegExp(keyword,'gi')
```

then  it will match Apple anywhere. But if your RegEx will look like this for example: /^Apple$/gim

```
new RegExp("^"+keyword+"$","gim")
```

in this example the pattern will match word Apple or apple sitting alone in a line so it will not match Apple Pie.

In other words if you will make your regular expression more specific you will be able to reduce false positive matches:)

Comment: Thank you. I will combine this with the other answer!